# VS code default all html files to Django templates & comments them in a wrong way (if I press ctrl + /)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

VS code default all html files to Django templates & comments them in a wrong way (if I press ctrl + /)

i.e it comments normal html files by adding {% comment %} & {% endcomment %} instead of the correct html comment < !--  -->

Answer (score 9):

Go to: File -> Preferences -> Settings 
and add this line to your USER SETTINGS

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.html": "html"
}
```

Comment: still very relevant. Thanks for this gem

Comment: when I go to file-> preferences-> settings I don't get an editable file.

Comment: @Akorian click on the little icon that looks like a file in the top right corner to see JSON version of settings

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was the (Djaneiro & some other Django) extensions, it made the html files default to django template, so it caused the comments to be wrong in HTML (when pressing ctrl + / ) (commenting them with {% comment %})